# Refresh jsf datatable, Method runs twice

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a table with repairs and you can bid on these repairs and the bids will be shown in the table as well as an accept button. When you hit the acceptbutton I want de datatable to refresh and set the acceptbutton to unaccept. When I debug and hit the accept button, I see that it runs the dashboardBean.acceptBid(bid) method twice. This way the bid.accepted will go from false to true and back to false. Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the necessary code:

```
public void acceptBid(Bid bid){
    activeBid = bid;

    if(bid.isAccepted()){
        repairService.clearBid(bid);
    }else{
        repairService.acceptBid(activeBid);
    }
}
```

And here's the page:

```
<h:commandButton id="showOpen" value="#{msg['welcome.button.showDashboard']}" action="#{dashboardBean.showDashboard}" update="table-open-wrapper"/><br/><br/>
                <h:panelGroup id="table-open-wrapper">
                    <h3>#{msg['welcome.title.openRepairs']}</h3>
                    <h:dataTable id="itemToRepair" value="#{dashboardBean.openRepairsArray}" binding="#{dashboardBean.dataTableOpen}" var="itemToRepair"> <ui:remove>rendered="#{dashboardBean.openRepairsVisible}"</ui:remove>
                        <h:column headerText="Open repairs">
                            <h:outputText value="#{itemToRepair}"/>
                        </h:column>
                        <br/>
                        <p:column headerText="bidsPerItem">
                            <ui:repeat value="#{itemToRepair.bids}" var="bid">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bid.repairer.username}"/>
                                <h:outputText value="#{bid.price}"/>
                                <h:column headerText="Buttons">
                                    <h:commandButton id="acceptItemBid" value="#{msg['welcome.button.acceptBid']}" rendered="#{!bid.accepted}" action="#{dashboardBean.acceptBid(bid)}" update="itemToRepair"/>
                                    <h:commandButton id="unacceptItemBid" value="#{msg['welcome.button.unacceptBid']}" rendered="#{bid.accepted}" action="#{dashboardBean.acceptBid(bid)}" update="itemToRepair"/><br/>
                                </h:column>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </p:column>
```

Comment: Which JSF implementation version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2

Comment: `h:commandButton` does not have ajax capability itself, `update` attribute is useless for it. please change accept/unaccept buttons to `p:commandButton`.